# Как передать instace объекта в функцию?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Проститите за тупой вопрос просто приходится учить ts походу дела. Как предать instance объекта в функцию?
Вот в одном файле експротирую инстанс класса вот так  `export default new ApiError();`
и в другом использую:

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";
import ApiError from '../errors/ApiError';

const errorHandler = function (err: ApiError, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Response {
    if (err instanceof ApiError) {
        return res.status(err.status).json({message: err.message});
    }
    return res.status(500).json({message: "Непредвиденная ошибка!"})
}
```

И мне высвечивает ошибка типа это не тип

```
: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/middlewares/ErrorHandlingMiddleware.ts:4:37 - error TS2749: 'ApiError' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof ApiError'?

4 const errorHandler = function (err: ApiError, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Response {
                                     ~~~~~~~~
src/middlewares/ErrorHandlingMiddleware.ts:5:24 - error TS2359: The right-hand side of an 'instanceof' expression must be of type 'any' or of a type assignable to the 'Function' interface type.

5     if (err instanceof ApiError) {
                        ~~~~~~~~

   at createTSError (/home/ihor/Test Task by Komah Ihor/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:587:12)
   at reportTSError (/home/ihor/Test Task by Komah Ihor/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:591:19)
   at getOutput (/home/ihor/Test Task by Komah Ihor/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:921:36)
   at Object.compile (/home/ihor/Test Task by Komah Ihor/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1189:32)
   at Module.m._compile (/home/ihor/T^: команда не найдена
est Task by Komah Ihor/node_modules/ts-node/src/inihor@ihor-GF65-Thin-9SEXR:~/Test Task by Komah Ihor$ TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
dex.ts:1295:42)
   at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
   at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/home/ihor/Test Task by Komah Ihor/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1298:12)
   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
^CTSError:: команда не найдена
```

как использовать тип  ApiError в єтом файле

Comment: Так вполне правильная ошибка - при экспорте ты инстанцировал _экземпляр_ `ApiError`, экземпляр объекта конечно же является _значением_, а не типом... Я бы описал интерфейс который реализуется классом `ApiError`, и этот интерфейс (или производный от него тип) использовал бы в качестве типа аргумента (так меньше вероятность запутаться/ошибиться, плюс не придется сильно рефакторить код если появятся еще классы-наследники).

Comment: Если интерфейс не хочешь, то экспортируй вместо экземпляра сам класс (это вроде очевидно из предыдущего коммента, но поясню на всякий случай...): без `new` и скобочек вызова. Класс объекта `ApiError`, в отличие от экземпляра - можно использовать и в качестве типа аргумента `err`, и в выражении с оператором `instanceof`.

Comment: @ yar85,  да тип то появился но ниже я обращаюсь к   err.status к полям екземпляра и мне выдает:
         error TS2339: Property 'status' does not exist on type 'ApiError'.

6         return res.status(err.status).json({message: err.message});
                                ~~~~~~

Comment: Значит, надо либо в класс добавить такое свойство, либо описать потомка этого класса, либо использовать интерфейс/пересечение.